# How to convert string datetime to timestamp with time zone?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I convert this string **"09/23/2022 12:44 PM EDT"** to timestamp with time zone using **"to_timestamp_tz"** function in **oracle 19c**?

Answer (score 0):

`EDT` and `EST` are ambiguous as they are only valid half the year. To be consistent, you need to use `US/EASTERN` instead:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '(EDT|EST)$',
           'US/EASTERN'
         ),
         'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI AM TZR'
       ) AS tz
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '09/23/2022 12:44 PM EDT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '06/23/2022 12:44 PM EDT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12/23/2022 12:44 PM EDT' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TZ |
| --- |
| 2022-09-23 12:44:00.000000000 -04:00 |
| 2022-06-23 12:44:00.000000000 -04:00 |
| 2022-12-23 12:44:00.000000000 -05:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/npyH49H8)

Comment: thank you this actually works, but i thought is there a way to convert string timestamp with "EDT" to timestamp with time zone